# ImageMagick upgrade on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, php, imagemagick

I installed `imagemagick` on my Ubuntu 16.04 server with this easy command:

```
apt-get install php-imagick
```

Everything is installed and is working fine with Nginx / php7.0-fpm.

The actual installed version is 6.8.9-9 and I would like to install the newer version 6.9.3. I can't do that with apt and I tried to do it with dpk by downloading files from [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/artful/main/base/imagemagick-6-common) and then running:

```
dpkg -i libmagickcore-6.q16-3_6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu2_amd64.deb libmagickwand-6.q16-3_6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu2_amd64.deb php-imagick_3.4.3~rc2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

But I get some dependencies issues, if I resolve them by upgrading some package I can't do any more `apt-get upgrade` without errors.

Can I download a binary of ImageMagick for PHP-FPM which would not depend on packages installed on the server?
If not any repository for a newer version of `imagemagick`?